# How to reset the changes that were pushed to git and then merged with another branch?

Tags: git

I pushed some changes on git, by mistake. And then those changes were merged with another branch.
Because of merging I am unable to reset the changes in initial branch.

How should I reset the changes that were pushed by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider reverting to a good state and pushing the commits that fix the mistake. This keeps the mistake in the history, but requires less coordination with anyone who has pulled your broken changes, and other branches can be fixed simply by merging.

The problem with resetting and pushing a shared branch is that the broken changes still appear in others' repos and branches.

If you really want to reset the branch:

Assuming the `master` branch started from a commit we'll call `good`, on top of which were added commits we'll call `broken`. The `feature` branch was branched off `master` and started with a few commits we'll call `before`, then was merged with `master` (which was `broken`) in a commit we'll call `merge-broken`, and other commits were made on top of that, we'll call them `after-broken`.

Here's how these branches might get fixed, discarding other changes to the `master` and `feature` branches:

```
git branch -f master good
git branch -f feature before
git checkout feature
git merge master
git cherry-pick merge-broken..after-broken
```

These changes can be pushed upstream, but as mentioned above this might be dangerous in a public or shared repo:

```
git push origin +master +feature
```

Other users may need to pull those branches with the `--force` flag, and may need to adjust their local branches in the same way.